# Python script running slow

Tags: python

For some reason, this code is running extremely slow

I have tried replacing proxies, but that didn't seem to be the issue

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

ipLogger = "";#link for logger
agent = "X";
referer = "X";
scrapeHttpsProxies = 0;

print("Botting Link: " + ipLogger);

proxies = open("https.txt", "r");

print("Found " + str(sum(1 for line in open('https.txt')))+ " HTTPS Proxies.");

while True:
    for x in proxies:
        if x != "":
            try:
                headers = {
                    "user-agent": agent,
                    "referer": referer
                };
                proxy = {
                    "https": x.strip()
                }
                req = requests.get(url=ipLogger, headers=headers, proxies=proxy, timeout=5);
                status = req.status_code;
                if status == 404:
                    print("Connection error - Bad Proxy");
                elif status == 403:
                    print("Connection error - Bad Proxy");
                elif status == 200:
                    print("Working request with proxy: " + x.strip());
                else:
                    print("Unknown Status Code:", status);
            except IOError:
                print("Connection error - Bad Proxy");

print("\nFinished sending requests!");
```

I expected this to run rather fast, and go through proxies fast, but it actually goes relatively slow

Comment: There's a difference between something being slow, and something taking a long time. If there's a 5 second timeout then it will take 5 seconds to timeout.

Comment: @PeterWood How would i be able to speed this up?

Comment: I agree with @PeterWood, in this case you will need to parallelize. If you have the latest python version I would recommend: 
https://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ it is not parallelizing but it would be extremely fast, and it will avoid complex multi process management.

Other than that this link can be of interest for you: https://www.eamonnbell.com/blog/2015/10/05/the-right-way-to-use-requests-in-parallel-in-python/

Comment: Put the code in two functions, `main` and `proxy_status`. Use `multiprocessing` to call `proxy_status` for each proxy in the file. Perhaps use [`Pool`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool) with [`map_async`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.map_async) so you can call the print function and see the progress.